# Can I get a list of B2C Tenant Users (Created using signin-signup policy) Using Graph Explorer?

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I'd like to use [Microsoft Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) to work with my Azure AD B2C Tenant.

Initially, all I want to do is retrieve a Custom Attribute that I've assigned to an application registration. The custom attribute will store the UserAppPermission value, a 'role' replacement for B2C since it doesn't natively support them.

Can I get a second set of eyes on my process? I'd like to make sure I'm reading this properly.

First goal: Get a list of applications registered to my B2C Tenant. Reasoning is... if the app registration doesn't appear then future queries are unlikely to be successful.

Resource#1 "[Manage Azure AD B2C with Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/microsoft-graph-operations#prerequisites)"  (Note B2C in the title)

(1) I registered an application in my B2C tenant with permissions in excess of the minimum, checked this process twice: [Register a Microsoft Graph application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/microsoft-graph-get-started?tabs=app-reg-ga) (Note B2C in the opening paragraph, and throughout the document).

(1a) Uncertain if the Azure portal was being buggy, I also registered this application with the 'Global Administrator Role' ... absolute overkill & insecure ..

(1b) I am certain that I assigned the appropriate Microsoft Graph API permissions in the app registration tab

(1c)  As described in the doc, I also granted the application the user administrator role, although that is contained within the global administrator role.

(1d) Per the doc, "Now that you've registered your management application and have granted it the required permissions, your applications and services (for example, Azure Pipelines) can use its credentials and permissions to interact with the Microsoft Graph API."

When I run "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/applications" to get a list of registered applications, all I see is the single App Registration our 'root' Azure account has for our Azure Functions App. Since this was an article on managing azure ad B2C with Microsoft Graph, I was expecting to see the applications registered to my B2C Tenant.

? Does anyone read (1d) to mean that I should not be able to use https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer, logged in as the B2C global administrator, and granting all permissions the endpoint requires, to make Microsoft Graph API queries?

---

Next goal: Get a list of users registered to my B2C Tenant

Resource#2 "[List Users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)" - the link to this resource was provided by Resource #1, link provided above.

(1) There only mention of B2C in this article is: "The $count and $search parameters are currently not available in Azure AD B2C tenants."

(2) The request to get all users is GET "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users"

(2a) The request returns a list of users for the MyOrg's root AD tenant, not the application's B2C tenant. Not surprising since there's nothing in the request to specify the B2C tenant.

(3) Another resource provides this request format: https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/.onmicrosoft.com/users, which specifies the b2c tenant.

(3a) This executes without error in Graph-Explorer but does not return any of the users that registered for the application using the sign-up/sign-in policy (Consumer B2C Users). It still returns a list of users for the 'root' Azure account.

---

Update re:specifying tenant in graph-explorer:
[image: graph explorer url & query]

While logged in to Graph Explorer us my work MS email which is registered as a global admin for our Azure account and owner of the B2C tenant I specified:

This returns a list of applications for the root Azure account, not app registrations for the B2C Tenant I specified. Perhaps I misunderstood the intent of this Graph API call.

I optimistically ran 'https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/identity/b2cUserFlows' with the tenant specified in the URL (as in screenshot). Result:

```
 "error": {
    "code": "AADB2C",
    "message": "'4fba2ea8-XXXX-XXXX-964e-99f48b79d925' is not an Azure AD B2C directory...
```

I'm still not certain what the UUID returned in the message represents. The UUID has no correlation, that I can find, with the tenant I specified in the URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that you are using an Azure account which is from your root AAD tenant.

You have two options to resolve it.

- Specify the tenant in the Graph Explorer URL:
  `https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer?tenant={Your b2c tenant}.onmicrosoft.com`. Still use that Azure account from root
  AAD tenant to sign in and you can get a list of applications and
  users of your B2C Tenant now.
- Another method is creating a new user in your B2C tenant and assign
  Global admin role to it. And then sign into
  `https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer` with
  this new user. Now you can list applications and users of your B2C
  Tenant as well.

---

**Update:**

Don't use a Consumer account (local account) for the second suggestion. You should create an AAD user (work account, format: `mytenantname.onmicrosoft.com` ) in Azure portal in B2C tenant and assign it global admin role.

[Overview of user accounts in Azure Active Directory B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-overview) for your reference.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I tried the first suggestion and updated my question accordingly. As for the second suggestion, I cannot login to the graph-explorer using a B2C (Consumer) account. Meaning that I doubt it would produce different results.

Comment: @IdusOrtus Don't use a Consumer account (local account) for the second suggestion. Create an AAD user in Azure portal in B2C tenant and assign it global admin.

Comment: @IdusOrtus `4fba2ea8-XXXX-XXXX-964e-99f48b79d925` may be the tenant id of your root AAD tenant. Check it in root AAD tenant in Azure Portal. If it is indeed the root AAD tenant, it means the `?tenant={Your b2c tenant}.onmicrosoft.com` doesn't take effect. But it works fine for me. You can try it in a private browser window or use the second method I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

@AllenWu's second solution was, in effect, correct but not explicit enough for me.

The [New user interface](http://#blade/Microsoft_AAD_IAM/UsersManagementMenuBlade/AllUsers) in the B2C Tenant offers three options for creating users: Create user, Invite user and Create Azure AD B2C user. Most of my work has revolved around B2C users so I did that and gave the user Global Admin rights and my Graph Explorer results were unchanged.

Another user provided [this suggestion](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/70467) and made it clear that I needed to create a user w/an email address of @*my-tenant-name*.onmicrosoft.com. I created such a user, assigned it Global Admin rights, and I was able to use Graph Explorer as I expected.

Note that users with an email of "SomeTestUser_gmail.com**#EXT#**@*my-tenant-name*.onmicrosoft.com do not behave in the same way.

Thanks for the suggestions & feedback & I hope this helps if you ended up here with the same question.

Comment: I don't think it's appropriate that  you mark your own answer . I have already given this solution in my answer and supplemented it in the comment. And I also provide another solution.  Anyway, glad to know this issue has been resolved.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback. The distinction of user type is very important though. I followed both of your suggestions and they didn't work for me. The first, specifying the tenant in the request uri, still hasn't worked for me but I have not tried it while logged in as @mytenantname.onmicrosoft.com w/global admin rights - that would probably work. The second didn't work when I created a B2C user (new user in my B2C tenant) and assigned Global Admin rights to it. It only works if an internal, not consumer or guest, user is created. Thanks again for your help - I really appreciate it!

Comment: @AllenWu I just noticed your comment to your answer. If you update your answer to include that, and specify the requirement for using an account with 
 email<at>mytenantname.onmicrosoft.com (user types are confusing for us new to ADB2C) I'll gladly mark your answer. Thanks again!

Comment: Updated the answer:) Thank you!